# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE every column except

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am using mysql through a socket, and I am updating 4000 records therefore I need to mass `INSERT` / `UPDATE` them to reduce network lag. The problem is that I have a column `datetime_inserted` that I want to set as `NOW()` when a record is first inserted, but never be replaced when it already exists, therefore `REPLACE` is not an option and I want to update the record, so `IGNORE` won't work.

I don't really understand the whole `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I want every column (40 or so) to update EXCEPT for `datetime_inserted`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO the_table (col1,col2,...,datetime_inserted) VALUES(value1,value2,...,NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2), ... #skip the datetime_inserted for the updates
```

Comment: I thought perhaps the ugly/bruteforce method was the way to do it but maybe I thought there would be a keyword to prevent from typing 40 columns.

Comment: That would be too easy :). A for loop might help though.